# VF simple thank you page

Tags: visualforce

After a user submits data on a vf page, I would like to send some simple HTML to the screen like `

## Thank you for updating your profile

Feel free to visit our website http://somewhere.com.

How to do this? Can I simply return html to the screen after the save method is done or must I make a VF/HTML and redirect to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

best solution just create a simple VF page with Thank you Note..

Once your save method done. redirect to this thank you page using PageRefernce method

Like IN you save method

```
public PageReference savemethod(){

    //other code

    return new PageReference('/apex/thankyouPage');

}
```

OR As suggested by [@Keith C](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/887/keith-c) return `Page.thankyouPage`

```
 public PageReference savemethod(){

        //other code

        return Page.thankyouPage;  
    }
```

Comment: Can you change this to `return Page.thankyouPage;` as that includes compile-time checking and is less verbose?